# Authentication request failure in PayPal Android SDK Live Mode

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I have to use the PayPal Android SDK, so I'm trying to Payment with Live mode from Android App. I'm trying to payment using Credit Card or Debit Card, but PayPal SDK return these error.

How can use PayPal in Live Mode. Please help me.

request failure with http **statusCode:401,exception:Unauthorized**

request failed with server response:
**{"name":"UNAUTHORIZED_PAYMENT","message":"Unauthorized payment.","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#errors","debug_id":"1b99b23b39a5e"}**

UNAUTHORIZED_PAYMENT

Comment: in which country you are trying to pay?

Comment: Right now from India, but actual payment from USA.

Comment: You have to register your merchant account in USA and also submit all documents and details to PayPal before you go to live

Answer (score 1):

you are getting that message because you are attempting to process direct credit card payments with a merchant account registered in a country where it's not available. Direct Credit Card transactions with the mSDK (and REST API in general) is available in US and UK only.